# Ansible run ends up with MODULE FAILURE?

Tags: ansible

I am unable to figure out anymore on this as there's no way that I know of to get a "real" error message out of ansible. I run the below

```
$ ansible -i /opt/ansible/ec2.py "tag_Function_app:&tag_Application_pro:&tag_Environment_pqa"   --private-key=~/.ssh/id_root_rsa -m shell --sudo -a "service httpd restart" -u root
```

But end up with a very nondescript error

```
10.221.142.0 | FAILED | rc=0 >>
MODULE FAILURE
```

What is exactly going on? Is there a way for me to further debug this? Trying to ssh strictly with the user / sshkey works fine?

Comment: Of note is that there was a bug report about this message on Ansible 2.0. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18846

Comment: Make sure you are not importing a tasks that don't exists e.g. `- import_tasks: jenkins.yml`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer is, the user did no have `sudo` perms. Thanks everyone =)

Answer (score 10):

This error also occurs when Python 2.x is not installed in `/usr/bin/python`. E.g. on Ubuntu 16.04 you have to install it:

```
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt install -y python-minimal
```

See also the [ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements).

Comment: I use latest AWS AMI Ubuntu 18.04 and struggling what causes the issue. Thanks, and it resolves the shell module issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer

In my case, it wasn't a sudo related problem. Posting for completion.

## tl;dr

Don't use a virtualenv with two different versions of ansible (one in OS and the over in pip-virtualenv)

### Explanation part

I had the same error with module "shell".

`ansible -i ~/ansible-hosts example01 -mshell -a 'df -Ph'` : MODULE FAILURE

`ssh example01 'df -Ph'` : no problem.

## Problem

The version I had in my Debian (installed w/ aptitude) was `2.2.1.0` and the one in my Virtualenv (installed with pip from the Virtualenv) was `2.2.2.0`.

## Resolution

I uninstalled both and then re-installed the one in the Virtualenv.

hth

Comment: great explanation, plus one

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be the case for everyone, but I just experienced this error due to a full root volume on the affected hosts.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting this as an answer, but a comment ;)

Comment: It was the answer I didn't see here that I needed when I got a bunch of "MODULE FAILURE" output, hence its an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I installed ansible in a virtual env and played with galaxy roles and different names for them, this scrambled them somehow and lead to this error message. Deleted the virtual env and started new, everything fine again.